# ios4 multitasking controls & background Audio features question

Tags: audio, ios4, multitasking

I'm pretty new to IOS4 audio/multitasking and i cant find an answer on this topic:

Got a, pretty easy, two part question:
What framework works in conjunction with the ipod framework?  Everyone's seen the pandora app, so the question is:

1. How do you get the app to notify the user that music is playing (via the purple play icon in the status bar)?
2. How does this become controllable via the multitasking control bar (ya know, the ones right next to the lock-aspect button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all the same process.

The play icon is added when you successfully link up your app with the remote play controls (remoteControlReceivedWithEvent). The controls are just events that are channeled to your remote control aware app.

TYPE of audio doesn't matter, as far as i know (MPAudioPlayer doesn't work in the background though).

Hope that helps the newer coders out there :)